# Are C++ initializers called in Objective-C synthesized properties?

Tags: c++, objective-c, properties, objective-c++

Are C++ initializers called in Objective-C synthesized properties?  Meaning if I write a custom initializer for creation from another object of the same type (C++) does the synthesized property setter call that initializer?

Comment: What do you mean? Maybe give some code and point out what you're asking about.

Comment: Code, man.  Need to see the code!

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by initializer you actually mean a C++ constructor. In a synthesized setter the copy constructor for the C++ object is called.

Comment: You can use a C++ class with a zero-argument constructor as an Objective-C instance variable. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Fixed my answer. Has been a while since I worked with Objective-C++.